# First ODEs - Bernoulli Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the differentiable function f with **$f(0) = −2$** for which the equation
**$1 + y^2(\sin t) + f(t)yy'=0$** 
is exact. Then solve the resulting equation.

I might be taking the wrong approach to this question, but so far I know $v = y^{1-r}= y^{-1}$ which means $v'=(-y^{-2})y'$. Multiplying $-y^{-2}$ to equation gives:

$$-y^{-2}-f(t)y^{-1})y'= \sin t.$$

I am stuck at this stage as I can't get the right substitution for $dv/dt$.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can take two possible approaches for this question:
1) Write the ODE as
$$(1+y^2\sin(t))\mathrm{d}t + f(t)y\mathrm{d}y=0$$
This ODE is exact iff $$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}(1+y^2\sin(t))= \dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}(f(t)y)$$
From this you should be able to find $f$. After that it should be easy to find the solution.

2) As a Bernoulli ODE, first divide by $y$ to get
$$y^{-1}+ y\sin(t) +f(t)y'=0$$
Then apply the substitution $v \mapsto y^2$ and solve the linear ODE that comes from that.